# Getting 502 error when I try to send email, server setup by django, postgres, nginx, gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am following this tutorial from digital ocean [How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Everything is working fine except when I try to send email using gmail it throws 502 bad gateway. nginx log file shows

> 94 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

gunicorn configuration

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=webuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/webuser/chhuti_ata
ExecStart=/home/webuser/venv/chhuti/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --
workers 3 --bind unix:/home/webuser/chhuti_ata/chhuti.sock 
chhuti.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ***.***.***.***;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/webuser/chhuti_ata;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/webuser/chhuti_ata;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/webuser/chhuti_ata/chhuti.sock;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please add config files

Comment: can you please check now

Answer (score 0):

I think that error from Nginx is indicating that the connection was closed early before it could complete sending the email. If you are sending emails via gmail, gmail sometimes [block the log-in](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) (and sending of emails) from unidentified log-ins or "insecure apps" (that would be the log-in from the server hosting your django application) for security purposes.

You may need to check your gmail security settings to manually ensure that gmail is allowing the web server running your django app (specifically, identify the server i.p.) to send emails.

If that doesn't work you may need to configure DJango to send e-mails asynchronously, see [here](https://medium.com/@EmadMokhtar/send-emails-asynchronously-from-django-3c1e41b526c3)

Comment: thank you, I have changed google setting to less secure settings. and changed timeout to 7500 too in nginx but yet no luck.

Comment: did your server log-in show up on the gmail security page. gmail has a log-ins history page that shows all the attempted log-ins; you need to allow the specific i.p. of your server

Comment: yes it did, after that I have changed to lower security settings.

Comment: maybe you need to send emails asynchronously ... are you using django-celery? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-email

Comment: I haven't tried that, i'll give it a try. Thanks for all of your effort.